# MySQL: Adding indices after huge insert -> Faster or not

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I've recently discussed the following scenario with a coworker:

(MySQL 5.x, InnoDB, single transaction)

- Table A 20 mio Entries
- Table B Empty (has several indices on it)

Query: `INSERT INTO B AS SELECT some_fields FROM A WHERE date < XY -- selects about 3/4, or 15 MIO elements`

Now to our questions:

- Main Question: Would it be faster to first deactivate/remove all indices  from Table B and then read them afterwards, or is this all the same?
- Bonus Question I: Any other ideas to improve this kind of query? it takes waaays to long IMHO.
- Bonus Question II: Write cache is deactivated on that disk, could that have a major impact (more than usual).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to do

```
ALTER TABLE B DISABLE KEYS
```

before running the insert. Otherwise MySQL tries to calculate after every insert. Once you've inserted everything:

```
ALTER TABLE B ENABLE KEYS
```

Once you do that MySQL will recalculate them all at once. It will still take some time but much less than doing it on each insert.

Improvements: Check that your date column on table A is indexed. It may be that your select is taking a long time if it's not.

I'm honestly not sure on the write cache question

Comment: This supports my understanding. Of course I will compare the runtimes it to get definite answer. About the date column: it wasn't my primary concern has a full table scan of A never takes as long as it currently takes to insert into B (which is several hours). Anyway,  I will check that as well. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I've read somewhere that `disable keys` doesn't work for `innodb`. Cannot confirm or disprove it though.